# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
> Current browser version is 116.0.5845.97 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Can anyone help me? I've seen some suggestions in other posts but none worked here. I am aware of the Selenium v4.6 update

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By




class ChromeAuto:
    def __init__(self):
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.service = Service()
        self.chrome = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.service, options=self.options)
        self.chrome.implicitly_wait(20)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114. LATEST\_RELEASE\_115 doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913935/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-this-version-of-chromedri)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Chrome `116+` you'll need `selenium` `4.11.2` at a minimum for the Selenium Manager to download `chromedriver` `116+` from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Then you'll be able to run basic Selenium scripts like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# Add your code here
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Every time chrome updates will I have to update selenium? Do I transform the codes into exe and distribute them to customers, in this case is there any way to make this update automatic? @MichaelMintz

Comment: It's hopefully a one-time thing for https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ - Upgrade to `selenium` `4.11.2` and then things should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue happen to me a few times and my fix was to add the actual chromedriver.exe file into the same folder as the python file. If your python file is inside of a self-made folder, for example, a folder named "test" in your downloads folder then add the chromedriver.exe file into that "test" folder. If your python file is not inside of a subfolder and you are still getting this issue then try updating selenium.

Comment: It happens that I distribute the code with colleagues, in which case each one uses a different version of chorme @Vanden

Answer (score 0):

Its adapted code (thanks chatgpt) from Michael Mintz for MacOS.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Specify the path to chromedriver
chromedriver_path = '/Users/altblog/Downloads/chromedriver-mac-x64/chromedriver'

# Create a WebDriver instance with options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

# Create a Service instance for chromedriver
service = Service(chromedriver_path)

# Create a WebDriver instance using the service and options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# Your code here

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the path of ChromeDriver, the corresponding version of ChromeDriver will be downloaded and used automatically. See the accepted answer.

Comment: @Raptor Really? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi8a3.png

Comment: Seems you have network problem connecting to the download server of ChomeDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I face same error during after installing selenium packege in

> The chromedriver version (116.0.5845.96) detected in PATH at E:\11.
> Screnshot_CLIENT_SERVER\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe
> might not be compatible with the detected chrome version
> (117.0.5938.63); currently, chromedriver 117.0.5938.62 is recommended
> for chrome 117.*,

Selenium packege not install letest webdriver version but it installwhich was letest at time when selenium packege updated.

> So you have to replace latest web driver with old webdriver remainedin package module

> For node js: node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).