# Unable to launch Maven project as it states Google Chrome is 116 and my system is only compatible upto 114

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.96 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome 
Host info: host: 'kashs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:140f:1c17:8d8b:b066%en0'
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.5', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at automation_basics.Facebook_Account.main(Facebook_Account.java:13)
```

I have already updated the ChromeDriver to 116 stable for MacBook.
Then checked the Selenium version and changed it to the latest one.
Also I updated at the usr/local/bin as well.

Despite everything I am still getting the above error.

Comment: include these line of codes, it might be work for you -     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76925094/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-crea