# Chrome driver 116.0.5845.96 doesn't works on windows11 pro

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, bdd

I have a problem with automation testing, I update Chrome on my machine one with Windows 11 Pro and another one with Windows 10 pro. I did the download for the driver from `https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/` and I downloaded the chromedriver  win64, as well for Mac machines and other browsers...
Now in Mac no problem, in Windows 10 Pro no problem, in Windows 11 Pro I have this error

```
    SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of 
    ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
    Current browser version is 116.0.5845.97
```

currently, I'm using Selenium 4.10.0

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76925365/7058266 - For Chrome 116+ you'll need selenium `4.11.0` at a minimum for the Selenium Manager to download chromedriver 116+ from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ (`4.11.2` for Python)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a solution on web either, so I try to update it manually.

Here are my steps:

1. download chrome driver at https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable
2. Goto C:\Users\**yourname**\.cache\selenium and copy chromedriver into \chromedriver\win32 or win64, just follow the version format.
3. edit selenium-manager.json, update **driver_version** as the version you download.