# The chromedriver version detected in PATH might not be compatible with the detected chrome version

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

im trying to run my discord-bot on REPLIT
my script uses selenium

```
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get(link)
```

crash log

```
The chromedriver version (108.0.5359.71) detected in PATH at /nix/store/i85kwq4r351qb5m7mrkl2grv34689l6b-chromedriver-108.0.5359.71/bin/chromedriver might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (116.0.5845.96); currently, chromedriver 116.0.5845.96 is recommended for chrome 116.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry
```

how do i install newer version like 116.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114. LATEST\_RELEASE\_115 doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913935/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-this-version-of-chromedri)

Answer (score 2):

Use [WebDriver-Manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) library to automatically update the driver's version.

**Installation:**

```py
pip install webdriver-manager
```

**Usage:**

```py
# selenium 3
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

```py
# selenium 4.0
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error is due to the fact that the *chromedriver* version that you will execute with selenium needs to match the *chrome browser* version that you are running (Which in your case is the latest = 116)

Step1 : Download the appropriate [chrome driver version 116 here](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)

Step2: Add imports to your code of selenium webdriver manager

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
```

Step3 : Add the downloaded chrome driver path to your code

For better help , here is a full working code example :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# chrome driver path to file downloaded
s=Service('........./chromedriver116')

# Setting up Chrome options - whichever options you need
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-features=NetworkService")
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'

# get url
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://example.com'
browser.get(url)
```