Setup for Rselenium
I am using Azul jdk to set Rselenium if is good until when I go into R
remote_driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",                           chromever = "114.0.5735.90",                           verbose = F) 

but there is an error on
Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 125.0.6422.113 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'MIE', ip: '10.0.0.235', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_412'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x002EA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x0027C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00185358]
    (No symbol) [0x001A61AC]
    (No symbol) [0x001A1EF3]
    (No symbol) [0x001A0579]
    (No symbol) [0x001D0C55]
    (No symbol) [0x001D093C]
    (No symbol) [0x001CA536]
    (No symbol) [0x001A82DC]
    (No symbol) [0x001A93DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0054AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0058A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0058456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003751E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00285F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00282328]
    (No symbol) [0x0028240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00274FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75757BA9+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7713BE7B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x7713BDFF+191]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]


Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.

What should I do? Since the current browser version is different than the supports chrome version

I would assume that you need to install that version of Chrome or update your version of Selenium. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913935/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-this-version-of-chromedri

I'm afraid wdman is still not updated to handle current chromedriver versions, though you can test this pull request - https://github.com/ropensci/wdman/pull/39 . Or perhaps try selinder, chromote or rvest::read_html_live(), if you must have something Chrome-based.
